# Retrieving Details from GitHub Repos

Tags: github

I'm looking for a way to get both the version number and license details from a repo providing I have the URL for the Repo. I have a way at the moment that doesn't work for all repos I am reviewing but it's basically html scraping.

I assume there is an API example somewhere that pulls these details?

some random examples

https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal

https://github.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version do you need ? If a `package.json` file is present, you can use it and get the version in it:

`curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant/master/package.json | jq -r '.version'`

For the latest release tag name (aka version), use

`curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/Microsoft/Terminal/releases/latest | jq -r '.tag_name'`

To retreive the license, use the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-a-repository-readme) and go to https://api.github.com/repos/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/license, e.g.

`curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/license | jq -r '.license.name'`
`

Comment: Hey Ponsfrilus, thank you for the comments. This is exactly what I needed! I appreciate you sharing the knowledge! have a great week :)